# Ubuntu 20.4 LTS terminal not opening

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, update-manager, canonical-livepatch, startup-disk

In my laptop, Dell Inspiron 5570, the terminal is not opening.

When I click on the terminal icon, in the activity tab it shows that it's loading but doesn't open. The same happens for some applications, like Livepatch, System Update, Additional Drivers, Software & Updates, Startup Disk & Terminal.

Comment: Have you tried the F12 key? That used to bring up a terminal on older versions of Ubuntu, but I don't know if it works on Ubuntu 20. You can also try ctl-alt-F2 (or another "F" key to see if you get a command prompt. then you can login and use the command line. Press ctl-alt-F7 to get back to your desktop.